# Why does my code run correctly sometimes, but not in other cases?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automated-tests, webdriver

I would like to make an automated testing to continuously click the cookie on https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(PATH))
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

language = driver.find_element(By.ID, "langSelect-EN")
language.click()

cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, "bigCookie")

for i in range(100):
    ActionChains(driver).click(cookie).perform()

time.sleep(400)
```

However, i don't know why, but  after clicking the language, **sometimes** it continues, **sometimes** it doesn't. I have to use time.sleep(5) before finding the cookie element for it to work consistently, any ideas why this happens? I don't get how my code can run inconsistently, even-though I'm not changing anything

I tried using explicit wait, but it also doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, "bigCookie")`, *why should that find an element*? How does the element get there? Is it already there in the page HTML, or does it come, for example, from some Javascript that runs after clicking the language-select button? Do you think it might take some time for that Javascript to run? Do you see how that would cause the observed problem?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood everything correctly, you get a selenium exception. You need to process it and wait on the page before loading the clickability of the elements. The following code should help you.Don't forget about the imports.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

import time

url = f'https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,"
              "application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
}


def get_result(url, headers):
    chrome_options = Options()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=".../chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver") # the path to your chromedriver
    driver.get(url)
    ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException,)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions) # let's set the timeout to 10 seconds, below we will wait until the element appears on the page or 10 seconds
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "langSelect-EN")))

    language = driver.find_element(By.ID, "langSelect-EN")
    language.click()
    

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "bigCookie")))
    cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, "bigCookie")
    
    for i in range(100):
        ActionChains(driver).click(cookie).perform()

    time.sleep(10)


def main():
    get_result(url=url, headers=headers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It works! I'm wondering why do we need headers? It also works if i remove it from the function parameters?

Comment: Headlines are rather needed to simulate the presence of a person, but I think it will work without them.

Comment: don't use time.sleep to explicitly block the code if you already have WebDriverWait. And if you are worried about getting rate limited, you can just use either async requests with their own pool executor or read the robots.txt.

Comment: Yes, in this code, time.sleep is more likely to view the result, it is not needed here in principle